# How to validate and replace an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my script. I'm validating if the value of variable named 'total' is not NaN.If its NaN then I want to remove the div which id is  '#no-rate_"+i' and append text to div 'new_rate_"+i+"' .

Weirdly, in the it doesn't make any changes to the divs. Even the style I added in each div specifying border and height also not  happening.

As checked in the console tab it does validates correctly.But the action to take if value is NaN or not NaN is wrong.

This is what shown in the console tab on f12

> [context: document, selector: "#no-rate_26"]context: documentselector:
>   "#no-rate_26"**proto**: e[0] searchResult.js:168 [context: document,
>   selector: "#new_rate_26"]context: documentselector:
>   "#new_rate_26"**proto**: e[0] searchResult.js:174 total NaN

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "fetch_tutor.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
//total set here. reviewPlus and reviewNeg are column name in table returned by php script(fetch_tutor.php)
           var total = data[i].reviewPlus + data[i].reviewNeg;
                if (isNaN(total)) {
                    console.log("lesser than 0" + total);
                    console.log($("#no-rate_" + i).text());
                    console.log($("#no-rate_" + i).text(" "));
                    $("#no-rate_" + i).text(" ");
                    $("#new_rate_" + i).html("No reviews yet");
                    console.log($("#new_rate_" + i).append("No reviews yet"));
                } else {
                    console.log("more than 0" + total);
                    total = data[i].reviewPlus + data[i].reviewNeg;
                }
                console.log("total " + total);

                $("#show_json").append("<div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns result_container' id=id_'" + i + "'><div  id='new_rate_" + i + "' style='border:1px #fff;height:50px;' class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-left>Nre rate here</div><div style='border:1px #ff0;height:50px;' class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center' id='no-rate_" + i + "'>id='no-rate_" + i + "' Rating: <span class='green'>" + data[i].plus + "</span> from <span class='reviews'><a id='" + data[i].user + "' class='review'>" + total + " reviews</a></span></div></div>");

            }
        }
    });
```

Or is there any better way in doing this?

Comment: what is total? where is it being set?

Comment: @BG101, edited my post. Total is sum of reviewPlus and reviewNeg. These values fetched from database via php script and they are integers.

Comment: But the action to take if value is NaN or not NaN is wrong -- What do you want it to do?